# gitなどでコンフリクトしたときの記法の名前を知りたい

Tags: linux, git

`git` や `hg` でmergeがコンフリクトしたとき、ファイルが以下のような内容になるかと思います。

この `<<<<<<<`, `========`, `>>>>>>>` を用いた記法に名前はあるのでしょうか。

```
...
<<<<<<< HEAD
hoge
=======
fuga
>>>>>>> develop
...
```

Comment: 正式名称があるのかもしれませんが、`<<<<<<<` や `>>>>>>>` は conflict markers, 記法に関しては conflict diff format などと呼ばれている様です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。検索するためのキーワードが知りたかったので、問題はほぼ解決です。

Comment: コメントは解答欄ではありません。正確か不正確かに関わらず回答に入力するようご協力いただけませんでしょうか。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2645/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%a1%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e8%a7%a3%e6%b1%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af-%e5%9b%9e%e7%ad%94%e3%82%92%e6%8a%95%e7%a8%bf%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%bb%e3%81%97%e3%81%84

Comment: ご指摘承知しました。以後気をつけます。

Comment: ernix さんの指摘は @metropolis さんに宛てたものだと思います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git-merge` のマニュアル内 [TRUE MERGE](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_true_merge)セクション、[CONFIGURATION](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-mergeconflictStyle)セクションでは "conflict marker" と呼称されています。

Answer (score 6):

@metropolis さんのコメントを引用:

> 正式名称があるのかもしれませんが、<<<<<<< や >>>>>>> は conflict markers, 記法に関しては conflict diff format などと呼ばれている様です。